# Microsoft exchange transport log will not start

Tags: exchange-2007, exchange

Microsoft Exchange transport log will not start. It tries to start and then stops.  We now cant receive or send any emails.  Can anyone help?

The errors below are displayed in the event viewer:

> Watson report about to be sent to dw20.exe for process id: 15892, with parameters: E12, c-RTL-AMD64, 08.03.0377.000, edgetransport, M.E.E.Internal, M.E.D.T.I.M.FactoryTable.CreateAgentFactory, System.OutOfMemoryException, 277a, 08.03.0377.000.  ErrorReportingEnabled: True

The log:

> Edgetransport (15416) Sender Reputation Database: The database engine is initiating recovery steps.

I'm running exchange 2007 which is part of windows 2008 SBS.

Answer (score 0):

Scan your database. The service will not start if a DB corruption happen.

Start cmd, go in your exchange bin directory and run Eseutil /r (or /p) if it's damaged a lot